# Highcharts.js How to put current time label in the end of xAxis

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a chart with dateformat xAxis. For example today is fifth ov nov. PointInterval is 1 day. PointStart - 3 of nov.

There will be "3 of NOV", "4 of NOV" and "5 of NOV" points. But the last point should be not a day, but current time.

like this: "3 of NOV", "4 of NOV", "today 16:30"

How to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Use formatter, where you can determine if label is last. See: http://jsfiddle.net/3bQne/664/

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type:'datetime',
        tickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
        labels: {
            overflow: 'justify',
            formatter: function (){
                if(this.isLast){
                    return 'today ' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%H:%M', (new Date().getTime()));    
                } else {
                    return Highcharts.dateFormat('%e of %b', this.value);
                }
            }
        }
    },

    series: [{
        pointStart: Date.UTC(2013, 10, 3),
        pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4]        
    }]
});
```